# Unsetting arrays with a specific value in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php

I am checking that certain elements in sub-arrays in a multidimensional array are not equal to a value and un-setting the array with that value from the multi array. I built a function so that I could easily implement this, however it doesn't appear to be working.

```
function multi_unset($array, $unset) {
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
        $arrayU = $array[$key];
        $check = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($unset); $i++) { // produces $array[$key][0, 2, 3]
            array_push($check, $arrayU[$unset[$i]]);
        }
        if(in_array("-", $check)) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
$arr = array(array("-", "test", "test", "test"), array("test", "test", "test", "test"));
$unset = array(0, 2, 3); // keys in individual arrays to check
multi_unset($arr, $unset);
print_r($arr); // Should output without $arr[0]
```

In this case, I'm checking if each sub-array has a "-" value in it and un-setting the array from the multi array. I am only checking specific keys in the sub-arrays (0, 2, 3) however it outputs an array without any changes. I figured I must have some scoping wrong and tried to use "global" everywhere possible, but that didn't seem to fix it.

Comment: You are not passing the array by reference... so `multi_unset($arr, $unset);` doesn't actually do anything to $arr. Either pass by refence using `multi_unset(&$arr, $unset);` or use your return value `$arr = multi_unset($arr, $unset);`.

Comment: To add to my previous comment: call-time pass by refrence was actually deprecated in PHP 5.3.0 and removed in 5.4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified your version a bit and handled the return value.

```
function multi_unset($array, $unset)
{
    $retVal = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        $remove = false;
        foreach($unset as $checkKey)
        {
            if ($value[$checkKey] == "-")
                $remove = true;
        }
        if (!$remove)
            $retVal[] = $value;
    }
    return $retVal;
}

$arr = array(array("-", "test", "test", "test"), array("test", "test", "test", "test"));
$unset = array(0, 2, 3);
$arr = multi_unset($arr, $unset);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: After studying your code, you are basically creating a new array of elements that are not equal  to "-". Is that correct? And they deprecated being able to change an array in a function. And $arr = multi_unset($arr, $unset); would fall under that category?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do some reading into Passing by Reference vs passing by value in PHP.
Heres some code that works with the given data set....

```
// Note the pass by reference.
function multi_unset(&$array, $unset) {
    foreach($array as $pos => $subArray) {
        foreach($unset as $index) {
            $found = ("-" == $subArray[$index]);
            if($found){
                unset($subArray[$index]);
                            // Ver 2: remove sub array from main array; comment out previous line, and uncomment next line.
                            // unset($array[$pos]);
            }
            $array[$pos] = $subArray;  // Ver 2: Comment this line out
        }
    }
    //return $array; // No need to return since the array will be changed since we accepted a reference to it.
}
$arr = array(array("-", "test", "test", "test"), array("test", "test", "test", "test"));
$unset = array(0, 2, 3);
multi_unset($arr, $unset);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: I think he actually wants to remove the whole sub-array from the array, not just the one key-value-pair from the subarray. Might be mistaken though.

Comment: Good call ccKep! In that case: `if($found){            unset($array[$pos]);}` and comment out the line after the if.